Kivy - How can I modify example for using ScrollView + GridLayout (Kivy-Garden Draggable)?
This Kivy - Draggable example works great:
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

from kivy_garden.draggable import KXDroppableBehavior, KXDraggableBehavior

KV_CODE = '''
#:import ascii_uppercase string.ascii_uppercase

<Cell>:
    drag_classes: ['card', ]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: .1, .1, .1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
<Card>:
    drag_cls: 'card'
    drag_timeout: 0
    font_size: 100
    opacity: .3 if self.is_being_dragged else 1.
    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Line:
            rectangle: [*self.pos, *self.size, ]
<Deck>:
    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Line:
            rectangle: [*self.pos, *self.size, ]

BoxLayout:
    Widget:
        size_hint_x: .1

    # Put the board inside a RelativeLayout just to confirm the coordinates are properly transformed.
    # This is not necessary for this example to work.
    RelativeLayout:
        GridLayout:
            id: board
            cols: 4
            rows: 4
            spacing: 10
            padding: 10

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_x: .2
        padding: '20dp', '40dp'
        spacing: '80dp'
        RelativeLayout:  # Put a deck inside a RelativeLayout just ...
            Deck:
                board: board
                text: 'numbers'
                font_size: '20sp'
                text_iter: (str(i) for i in range(10))
        Deck:
            board: board
            text: 'letters'
            font_size: '20sp'
            text_iter: iter(ascii_uppercase)
'''


class Cell(KXDroppableBehavior, FloatLayout):
    def accepts_drag(self, touch, ctx, draggable) -> bool:
        return not self.children

    def add_widget(self, widget, *args, **kwargs):
        widget.size_hint = (1, 1, )
        widget.pos_hint = {'x': 0, 'y': 0, }
        return super().add_widget(widget, *args, **kwargs)


class Card(KXDraggableBehavior, Label):
    pass


class Deck(Label):
    text_iter = ObjectProperty()
    board = ObjectProperty()

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.opos):
            if (text := next(self.text_iter, None)) is not None:
                card = Card(text=text, size=self._get_cell_size())
                card.start_dragging_from_others_touch(self, touch)
            return True

    def _get_cell_size(self):
        return self.board.children[0].size


class SampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV_CODE)

    def on_start(self):
        board = self.root.ids.board
        for __ in range(board.cols * board.rows):
            board.add_widget(Cell())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SampleApp().run()

and I need to modify this app for using ScrollView in "droppable" zone (as you can see on screenshot) but when only change RelativeLayout to ScrollView, ScrollView not works.
In my "experiments" i have only two states: ScrollView works, but it isnt works droppable functionality or droppable functiononality works, but it isnt possible to scroll cards.
Please, how can i customize this examlpe?


You must follow the directions as described in the ScrollView documentation. In order for the ScrollView to work, its child must have its size specified (typically using minimum_size or minimum_height).
Try changing the scrollable area to:
# RelativeLayout:
ScrollView:
    size_hint_x: .7
    do_scroll_x: False
    GridLayout:
        id: board
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        cols: 4
        rows: 40
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10

In order for the minimum_height to work, the sizes of the children of the GridLayout must have well defined sizes. This requires some changes to the Cell definition:
<Cell>:
    drag_classes: ['card', ]
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 50, 80
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: .1, .1, .1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

with these changes, I think your code will work.
